# Rigid Body physics objects keep exploding

Tags: physics

I have a remeshed Susanne with some fractures. Suzanne has a `Passive Rigid Body` with collisions shape set to `Mesh`. Fractures are set to `Active`, also with `Mesh` collisions shape.

[image]

Expected results would be for fractured objects to fall/slide using gravity, what I'm getting is an instant explosion of the fractures.

[image]

I've tried changing `Rigid Body World` scene settings (`Split Impulse`, `Solver Iterations`, `Substeps`), I've tried changing various Rigid Body settings (`Friction`,) and only getting more weird results. Tried scaling objects up ×10, the explosion was a bit smaller bit it introduced other issues like weird sliding, also this makes Suzanne ~20m in height which doesn't sound right. Anything else I could try?

Scene: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgdmxavlnf2hbur/physics_explode.blend?dl=1

Comment: You could switch the pieces from Mesh to Convex, in the Scene panel > Rigid Body World > decrease the Substeps Per Frame down to 1, and it will work better but there may be a better way...

Comment: @moonboots thank you for the reply: yes I've tried that, unfortunately I believe this only slightly conceals the issue: the objects still explode, just in a different way. Plus fractures start to fall through the floor due to degraded Substep and because of the convex shape they start to push each other much stronger :(

Comment: i have no idea how you made the fractures...but i think they aren't all manifold and some faces are wrong. And of course i would change the margin of all parts to 0. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A5x6.png

Comment: @Chris I’ve decimated them (when they were manifold the result was the same). Changing margins didn’t change anything unfortunately:(